# Invalid verification code format facebook oauth 100

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, sorcery

I am integrating my app on facebook
But its give an error with code 191

```
{"message"=>"Invalid verification code format.", "type"=>"OAuthException", "code"=>100, "fbtrace_id"=>"FoiD8d/qbxS"}:
```

{"error":{"message":"Invalid verification code format.","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"FoiD8d/qbxS"}}

My Site url : http://uae.local.me:3000/

Callback_url: 'http://uae.local.me:3000/oauth/callback'

Valid OAuth redirect URIs : http://uae.local.me:3000/oauth/callback